# Post to Facebook group wall and tag members - Graph API - C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently making a web application that so far has created a Facebook group, and can now post to the wall of that group:

Creates the group:

```
        dynamic fbInfo = fb.Post("/v2.2/" + appId + "/groups", new
        {
            name = GroupName,
            description = GroupDesc,
            admin = PersonID
        });
```

Post to the wall of the group:

```
        dynamic fbInfo = fb.Post("/v2.2/" + GroupID + "/feed", new
        {
            message = "This is a test message"
        });
```

So now I would like to tag a member of the group in this post and I am unsure on how to do that.
I have tried - @[PersonID:1:PersonName] but that doesn't quite do it, any ideas people? :)

EDIT:

If no one knows of a way to tag people using graph APIs then does anyone know how to POST an image to a facebook group (that the app has created)?

```
        dynamic fbInfo2 = fb.Post("/v2.2/" + groupID + "/photos", new
        {
            access_token = token,
            message = "This is the caption stuff",
            photo = @"/Content/Images/Image1.jpg"
        });
```

I tried this code however it requires the user access token instead of the app access token.

Comment: Tagging users in simple posts made via API is not possible any more, that was removed a long time ago because it created to much spam. You can only tag users in Open Graph stories; but that is rather for real-world actions that users undertake together – [mentioning](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.2#mentions) might be more appropriate for a game. And publishing photos via `/group_id/photos` is not even documented at the moment. You might have better luck publishing Open Graph stories with objects that include a photo instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can [tag or mention users in Open Graph stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.2?locale=de_DE#people), but I'm not sure if you can do it in a general case without users doing it manually. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish with the app, that may or may not be helpful.

You can post photos to an album if you have a link to one; however, I *think* this is limited to users and pages. It would be a real hack, but you *can* [change a group's cover photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/groups?locale=de_DE#update) for groups you generated with the app, so that would at least let you post photos.

The group API for apps isn't terribly robust, though, sadly. Is making a user/page for the app and posting via that an option?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object for Facebook API class Which we Downloaded..

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => $config['App_ID'],
     'secret' => $config['App_Secret'],
     'cookie' => true
    ));
```

Get group Id of which you post a link

```
 $group_id = $_GET['group'];
```

This is for Image Posting

```
$publish = $facebook->api('/'.$group_id.'/feed', 'post',
        array('access_token' => $access_token,
        'message'=> 'Testing',
        'from' => $config['App_ID'],
        'to' => $group_id,
        'caption' => 'caption',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'link' => 'http://www.google.com/',
        'picture' => 'full path of Image',
        'description' => 'Testing'
        ));
```

This is for Message or Status Posting
$publish = $facebook->api('/'.$group_id.'/feed', 'post',
        array('access_token' => $access_token,'message'=>"This is the message" .'   via IOS Demo',
        'from' => $config['App_ID']
        ));

Comment: This looks interesting however I am not sure if this will work in c#. Unless you have a c# example?